# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads', json.loads()

Tags: python, json

snippets

```
    import json
    teststr = '{"user": { "user_id": 2131, "name": "John", "gender": 0,  "thumb_url": "sd", "money": 23, "cash": 2, "material": 5}}'
    json = json.load(teststr)
```

throws an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

How to solve a problem?

Comment: Could you give more details - this is JS? Can you give link to snipped?

Comment: try loads instead of load

Comment: The error message doesn't match your example. `json.loads` is never called as part of direct input. Did you by chance bind a JSON data string to the name `json`?

Comment: It should be `.loads()`. Try with that.

Comment: json = json.load(teststr) => out_json = json.loads(teststr) and test again.

Comment: dont call your variable `json`. if you do that, the next time you try to call `json.loads` (or `json.ANYTHING`, it's going to attempt to call it on the string object, not the module.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load) takes in a file pointer, and you're passing in a string. You probably meant to use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.loads) which takes in a string as its first parameter.

Secondly, when you `import json`, you should take care to not overwrite it, unless it's completely intentional: `json = json.load(teststr)` **<-- Bad**.
This overrides the module that you have just imported, making any future calls to the module actually function calls to the dict that was created.

To fix this, you can use another variable once loaded:

```
import json
teststr = '{"user": { "user_id": 2131, "name": "John", "gender": 0,  "thumb_url": "sd", "money": 23, "cash": 2, "material": 5}}'
json_obj = json.loads(teststr)
```

**OR** you can change the module name you're importing

```
import json as JSON
teststr = '{"user": { "user_id": 2131, "name": "John", "gender": 0,  "thumb_url": "sd", "money": 23, "cash": 2, "material": 5}}'
json = JSON.loads(teststr)
```

**OR** you can specifically import which functions you want to use from the module

```
from json import loads
teststr = '{"user": { "user_id": 2131, "name": "John", "gender": 0,  "thumb_url": "sd", "money": 23, "cash": 2, "material": 5}}'
json = loads(teststr)
```

Comment: My favorite is the last version since it's the most clear and restrictive (i.e. polluting global namespace with functions you won't use or accidentally override)

Comment: Im actually having the same problem and I am using json.loads